# select and modify material in a three.js scene

Tags: javascript, select, three.js, key-value

i have a scene(object) json file with this structure that i load with ObjectLoader.
[image]
Once added in a scene i want to modify texture to add parameters like THREE.SmoothShading, add an envMap...
i know how to find an object:   var obj = scene.getObjectByName( "bas", true );
but i have to idea how to select a material and make modification that apply to all object using this material

Can't find anything on the web, could someone help please ?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can traverse your scene and set the `castShadow` flag on your objects. You can add more checks in there.

```
object.traverse( function ( child ) {

    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

        child.castShadow = true;

    }
});
```

Comment: i should have post the wrong answer below in the same time you posted your answer so i did not see it until today. Thanks, Thanks, Thank. But i leaded me to an error i posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088960/three-js-traverse-a-object-with-a-scene-and-not-wanting-to-traverse-the-scene-of), can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first when a scene/object is loaded into three.js it don't have the same structure anymore

```
THREE.Scene {id: 1, uuid: "EF1E7D35-66B9-466E-98B6-E62FC4A7AF46", name: "", parent: undefined, children: Array[1]…}
  __lights: Array[3]
    0: THREE.DirectionalLight
    1: THREE.DirectionalLight
    2: THREE.DirectionalLight
  length: 3
  __proto__: Array[0]
  __objectsAdded: Array[0]
  __objectsRemoved: Array[0]
  __webglFlares: Array[0]
  __webglObjects: Array[17]
  __webglObjectsImmediate: Array[0]
  __webglSprites: Array[0]
  .....
```

so if you want to modify the first light, you can do

```
scene.__lights[0].castShadow << true;
```

or i guess

```
scene.__lights[0] << {castShadow: true}
```

more coming as soon as learn it.

Comment: This is definitely not the way to go. How about storing the things you want to change before you add them to the scene.

Comment: @gaitat Hi, it's a pleasure to read from you. What i want in fact is adding cast and received shadow, add a envMap and THREE.SmoothShading to the object, but last thing i want is to loose my object structure and positions in space. is the helloracer.com/webgl/ a good example ? I was looking for more simple example, not find it yet.

Comment: Or maybe this is the way [/src/loaders/ObjectLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/ObjectLoader.js) i'm still searching...